# Forge API to translate InventorParams of {URL}/workitems into supported format like svf,dwg

Tags: node.js, api, autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-designautomation

**Didn't get idea to translate the model InventorParams.url to any supported formats like SVF,DWG,Obj**

sending data:{InventorParams.url} on endpoint /workitems by axios

---

```js
axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/da/us-east/v3/workitems',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ******',
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        data: JSON.stringify({
        activityId: 'BAsBRLiyiaHR1X9eYiAI4ATPmdcuZ5Pf.NamiliftActivity+beta',
        arguments: {
          InventorDoc: {
             url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/1a2ac1d9-a8af-4aa2-b9d1-8b0fde21bcf3?region=US',
             pathInZip: 'MasterAssembly.iam'
          },
          InventorParams: {
            url: 'data:application/json,{"ProjectNumber":"12345","ProjectName":"8000-2016","PreparedBy":"Nami","DrawingNumber":"Nami","CommissionNumber":"","ElevatorDesignation":"","ElevatorNumber":"","Logo":"NamiLift","LanguageOptions":"ENG","Standard":"PL400","NumberOfFloor":2,"LengthOfCar":2000,"WidthOfCar":1100,"Pits":true,"PitHeight":50,"ZoneSectionStart":239,"HeightAboveTopElevator":0,"ElectricBoxSide":"a","ElectricBoxFloorNo":"0","ElectricBoxDefault":false,"OuterRoof":false,"OuterRoofSide":"A","WindowsSectionA":"0-0","WindowsSectionB":"0-5000","WindowsSectionC":"0-0","WindowsSectionD":"0-0","DefaultDoorSize":false,"Colorelevator":"RAL 9001","Colordoor":"RAL 9001","Safelinemx2":false,"Safelinemx2gsm":false,"Schoolcontrolassa":false,"Schoolcontrol":false,"Intercom":false,"Callsend":false,"Firealarmdrive":false,"Folderseat":false,"Floorvoiceannouncement":false,"Lsfcable":false,"Telephone":false,"Keyswitch":false,"Ups":false,"Comments":"-","LiftHeightLevel0":0,"DoorSideLevel0":"A","TypeOfDoorLevel0":"A1","DoorHingeLevel0":"Right","DoorSizeLevel0":900,"DoorHeightLevel0":2000,"DoorCloserLevel0":true,"CanopyLevel0":true,"CallBoxLevel0":true,"LiftHeightLevel1":5000,"DoorSideLevel1":"A","TypeOfDoorLevel1":"A1","DoorHingeLevel1":"Right","DoorSizeLevel1":900,"DoorHeightLevel1":2000,"DoorCloserLevel1":false,"CanopyLevel1":false,"CallBoxLevel1":false}',
            'OutputPDF': {
                    'url': fileName.resultZipUrl,
                    'headers': {
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + values.access_token,
                        'Content-type': 'application/octet-stream'
                    },
                    'verb': 'put'
            },
            onComplete: 'onComplete': {
                    'verb': 'post',
                    'url': config.credentials.callback_url +'/api/forge/datamanagement/signanddownload'
            }
       }
    }
})
```

---

***WorkItem Output***

```js
{"status":"pending","stats":{"timeQueued":"2022-02-09T03:31:43.525012Z"},"id":"27fa82758b794111a91025ed69da6fec"}
```

This is the workitem/:id response for that InventorParams

[image: workitem/:id]

This is the txt file which i am getting from reportUrl of workitem/:id response

[image: report.txt]

---

**From report.txt file oss/v2/signedresources GET ZIP (InventorDoc.pathInZip name) with this content**

[image: input: verb -"GET"]
[image: oss/v2/signedresources]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **activity** you pasted seems to only be about creating a **PDF** for the drawing of a given **Inventor** model - see **OutputPDF** output parameter.

**InventorParams** simply provides a **json** file for the **work item** that the code in your **app bundle** can read, and use the values in it to modify the model accordingly using the **Inventor API**.

To better understand how the **input and output parameters**, inc the **json** file are used exactly by the **app bundle**, please have a look at the tutorial here:
https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/modifymodels

Comment: I am getting this while trying /modelderivative/v2/designdata/jobs The client_id specified does not have access to the api product

Comment: And i created object signedUrl locations for .svf , .dwg in .......@POST /bucket/:bucketKey/object/:objectKey for .svf , .dwg , .zip...... but i am getting empty folders in download of .dwg and .svf and .zip too and other download is fine like pdf and  InventorDoc.pathInZip

Comment: You should double-check that the Forge app whose client id you are using has Model Derivative API enabled - see last section here https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/401-unauthorized-403-forbidden